# impala - how to convert a delimited column to multiple rows

Tags: sql, hive, impala

The value of column scores are delimited by comma. Each userid has at least a score and there is no upper limit for the number of scores of each userid.

```
+--------+---------+
| userid | scores  |
+--------+---------+
| u1     | C,B,A   |
| u2     | A       |
| u3     | A,C     |
+--------+---------+
```

I want to get the result by 'select ...' sql

```
+--------+---------+
| userid | score   |
+--------+---------+
| u1     | C       |
| u1     | B       |
| u1     | A       |
| u2     | A       |
| u3     | A       |
| u3     | C       |
+--------+---------+
```

In hive, lateral view explode(split(score,',')) may realize the requirement,

```
select userid, score from my_table lateral view explode(split(scores,',')) scores as score;
```

However impala does not support explode.

Is there an alternative way to realize it in impala?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399187/comma-delimited-string-to-individual-rows-impala-sql

Comment: it does not work,  split_part function just split string but can not convert to multiple rows

Comment: can I assume that there is maximum 5 different scores in your table?

Comment: Each userid has at least a score, there is no upper limit for the number of scores of each userid.

Comment: What is the data type of column scores?

Comment: data type of scores is string